# Determinant property

Tags: determinant

My question is: "If determinant of $A^2$ is $0$ can we also say that determinant of $A$ is $0$?"

I have tried to argue that it is by saying that if $A^2 = 0$ then $A$ must be $0$ so determinant is also $0$.

Comment: Your argument is wrong: a matrix may be nilpotent without the matrix being $0$ (example: $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first sentence is correct, since you can make use of the property of  $\mbox{det}(AB)=\mbox{det}(A)\mbox{det}(B)$, finding 
$$0=\mbox{det}(A^2)=\mbox{det}(A)^2\to \mbox{det}(A)=0$$
However, your last reasoning is uncomplete, since there are matrices (different from zero) which can have determinants equal to zero. For example 
$$\left(\begin{array}{} 1&1\\1&1\end{array}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand I was wrong with my reasoning but thank god that property saved me :)